# Preview of my uploaded assets to Private Azure blob storage is not showing in strapi dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, strapi

[enter image description here][1]The preview of my uploaded assets is not showing in Strapi dashboard after uploading the file to my Private Azure blob storage. I am using my storage access key to provide permission to Strapi. I am able to upload and delete the file through the Strapi dashboard but the preview and download are not available. Any quick help will be much appreciated. Struggling with this for a couple of days.

Below is the code I am using in middleware.js of Strapi code

````
    name: "strapi::security",
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          "connect-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
          "img-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "blob:",
            "dl.airtable.com",
            "https://market-assets.strapi.io",
            "https://*.blob.core.windows.net",
            "https://*.blob.core.windows.net/my_bucket_name",
          ],
          "media-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "blob:",
            "dl.airtable.com",
            "https://*.blob.core.windows.net",
            "https://*.blob.core.windows.net/my_bucket_name",
          ],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },```


Below is the configuration where I am giving permission access to Strapi for Azure

```upload: {
      config: {
        provider: 'strapi-provider-upload-azure-storage',
        providerOptions: {
          account: env('STORAGE_ACCOUNT'),
          accountKey: env('STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY'),
          serviceBaseURL: env('STORAGE_URL'),
          containerName: env('STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME'),
          defaultPath: 'assets',
          maxConcurrent: 100,
          expiresIn:3600,
        }
      }
    },```
[Below is the link where you can find the image][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhZrN.png
````

Comment: could you please share your code

Comment: Hey @Sampath, I have updated the code that I am using.

Comment: This might help [you](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-upload-azure-storage?activeTab=readme)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Sampath, but I have already configured it the way the packages suggest. Still, I am not able to get the preview. But now I have figured out that it has nothing to do with Strapi, but with the Private URL that Azure generated. That is throwing 404 not found

Comment: Yeah, the app is working fine, I am able to upload and delete assets to private blob through strapi Dashboard. Just not getting the preview or the download from the Strapi dashboard

Comment: @Sampath - we are using this approach as well, but at times, when we upload multiple assets we run into issues. Are there any performance related issue or considerations we need to make while using this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Followed this [MSDoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-upload-azure-storage?activeTab=readme) for Srapi.

**Code:**

```js
account: env("STORAGE_ACCOUNT"),
        accountKey: env("STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY"),
        serviceBaseURL: env("STORAGE_URL"), // optional
        containerName: env("STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME"),
        defaultPath: "assets",
        cdnBaseURL: env("STORAGE_CDN_URL")
```

```js
  "media-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "blob:",
            "dl.airtable.com",
            /**
 * Note: If using a STORAGE_URL replace `https://${process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net` w/ process.env.STORAGE_URL
 * If using a CDN URL make sure to include that url in the CSP headers process.env.STORAGE_CDN_URL
 */
            `https://${process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net`,

          ],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
```

- Make sure to please the folder in the respective path of the app.

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Is your Azure blob access is private?

Comment: we can upload files even if the Container access level is a private (Or) blob (or) container.     we can  have any access level according to the requirement. i Keep it as Container

Comment: I got you, but my problem is I am able to upload and delete to the container through Strapi, but the preview for that uploaded media is not available. If you please scroll up to my original question, I am adding the Screeshot of what I am seeing after uploading the media in strapi dashboard

Comment: I will check. try to Raise a new question.